# onClick div changes color and back to color when clicking on the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to point out which div I clicked on to prevent confusing as the pop up menu that comes out of it on my site will be both the same just different links but same buttons. Now my problem is that i cant figure out how i can manage to do it been stuck on it for quite some time now. My site is in Wordpress for the info. The color of the text doesnt really matter atm.
The code does work but i want that when i hit "juicyplants" the color changes and when i hit "leafyplant" that color changes and "juicyplants" go back to normal. with the changing colors i mean the already presenting ones.
My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="clickOne" class="clickDesign">
<h2 class="fs20 nobold">Leafy Plants</h2>
</div>
<div  id="clickTwo" class="clickDesign">
<h2 class="fs20 nobold">Juicy Plants</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="leafyPlants">
Leafy Test
</div>
<div id="juicyPlants">
Juicy Test
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   #leafyPlants{
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

#juicyPlants{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

h2 {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    width:150px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  $("#clickOne").on('click', function() {
   $("#leafyPlants").fadeIn();
   $("#juicyPlants").fadeOut();
});
$("#clickTwo").on('click', function() {
   $("#leafyPlants").fadeOut();
   $("#juicyPlants").fadeIn();
})
```

Comment: The code you provided seems to "work" (http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Pcn5a/), can you please clearly explain what you want it to do?

Comment: Please, specify what error you are getting. I can't find a question here.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'Now my problem is that i cant figure out how i can manage to do it been stuck on it for quite some time now.'? That doesn't make sense to me

Comment: The code does work but i want that when i hit "juicyplants" the color changes and when i hit "leafyplant" that color changes and "juicyplants" go back to normal

Comment: The colour of which element changes? The one pressed, or the one you show/hide?

Comment: i just can't figure out a way to change the color on click and return back to normal when you click the other its not in the code here but i dont know what to add to my code to make it happen

Comment: the one presented is the one that i need to change

Comment: If I understand your: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Pcn5a/1/ If not, please explain step by step :)

Comment: You could do something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/ve5eL/2/

Comment: Better with classes: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Pcn5a/2/#update

Comment: ^ You could optimise it even further, by just having 1 click event, and using `data-` attributes to point to which `divs` you want to fade in.

Comment: @Nick R: Indeed... but I did not want to confuse him any further :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie that one is even better as i need gradient on it becuase it will be for an background color but needed an simple template for the fiddle haha Thank you so much. Nick Thanks for the info but I prefer the smaller code haha and its all i needed haha its all clear now. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to change classes and use styling:

### jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Pcn5a/2/#update

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickOne").on('click', function () {
        $('.clickDesign').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#leafyPlants").fadeIn();
        $("#juicyPlants").fadeOut();
    });
    $("#clickTwo").on('click', function () {
        $('.clickDesign').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#leafyPlants").fadeOut();
        $("#juicyPlants").fadeIn();
    })
});
```

### in style add:

```
.active{
    color: green;
}
```

It is better to data-drive any menu system and reduce the code:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Pcn5a/3/

### JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.clickDesign').on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.clickDesign').removeClass("active");
        $this.addClass("active");
        // Use the id in the data-target attribute
        $target = $($this.data('target'));
        $(".target").not($target).fadeOut();
        $target.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

### Html (has data-target attributes)

```
<div>
    <div id="clickOne" class="clickDesign" data-target="#leafyPlants">
         <h2 class="fs20 nobold">Leafy Plants</h2>

    </div>
    <div id="clickTwo" class="clickDesign" data-target="#juicyPlants">
         <h2 class="fs20 nobold">Juicy Plants</h2>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="leafyPlants" class="target">Leafy Test</div>
<div id="juicyPlants" class="target">Juicy Test</div>
```